# Sql-Update field only when value is NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have searched for 2 days now to no avail.

I want to change the following code so it only updates FORM1 when FORM1 field is NULL.

```
$sql="UPDATE TABLE39 set FORM1= $5600 where FORM34 = 40";//WORKS FINE
```

I am looking for a code that will be like:

```
$sql="IF FORM1= NULL, UPDATE TABLE39 set FORM1= $5600 where FORM34 = 40"
```

BUT IF FORM1 NOT EQUAL TO NULL, SHOW ERROR;

Comment: add it in the `WHERE` clause, example: `UPDATE TABLE39 set FORM1= $5600 where FORM34 = 40 AND FORM1 IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE39
set FORM1= $5600
WHERE FORM1 IS NULL AND
    FORM34 = 40
```

Answer (score 0):

You have change $5600 to two variables then

```
$sql="UPDATE TABLE39 set FORM1= IF(FORM1 IS NULL,$5600, $5600) where FORM34 = 40"
```